# Функция разделение отдельных слов в неизвестной строке с точкой и двоеточием [Python]

Tags: python, функции, замена, python-3.10, разделение-строк

Есть функция, которая разделяет и помещает в отдельные переменные, слова в неизвестной строке где 100% содержится **точка** и **двоеточие** которые разделяют слова, т. е. *папки* вот пример такой строки:

```
x = "org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:3.8.5"
```

Так же известно, что структура *папок* всегда такая:

**ПервыйДомен.ВторойДомен.ТретийДомен:Имя:Версия**

Также не мало важно чтобы Имя осталось целое

Количество Доменов может меняться, но 100% не меньше 2 и не больше 3

Желательно сделать это с помощью **.split** или **.replace**

Заранее спасибо

Comment: если есть такая функция, то в чем проблема?

Comment: желательно такие вещи делать регулярками, как по мне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
domains, name, version = x.split(':')
domains = domains.split('.')

if len(domains) == 2:
    domain1, domain2 = domains

else:
    domain1, domain2, domain3 = domains
```